# Objective C initialization of a derived NSObject and further assignation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsobject, assign

I'm not sure how to manage this, as objective-c is wierd enough for me
I'm have this derived class

```
@interface DoctorsSet :  NSObject  {    NSString *tableid;
    NSString *doctor_name;
    NSString *doctor_surname;
    NSString *city;
    NSString *State;
    NSString *phone; }
```

It has a custom constructor on which I'm initializing the properties as params...

THe problem is I have several functions that return this type, so how so I assign to a temporary local variable this type, or if my data comes from a NSMutableArray and I want to get that object at index ID

here are the 2 cases which I couldn't handle, because on assign it give an access error

```
    NSMutableDictionary *doctors_set;   

    for(i=[doctors_sets count]-1;i>=0;i--) {
         //this doesn't work 
         DoctorsSet * set=[doctors_set objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

i don't want to use **for(DoctorsSet *set in doctors_sets)** 
because i want to pass the array in the reverse order....

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the end goal is to go in reverse use

```
for (DoctorsSet *set in [doctors_sets reverseObjectEnumerator])
```

Comment: And if you’re feeling adventurous, you can use `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]` passing `NSEnumerationReverse` as the first argument.

Comment: I figure blocks at this point in the conversation would confuse things :)

Comment: yes this I could acomplish by using a reverse methos on nsarray. but how could it be done with a simple for . It's just that objective-c is so confusing sometimes..., I'm struggling to understand when I can assign something and when I have to initialize it then use a method to copy the contents of the array object and stuff like that...